# RHEL ubi8 package A requires B but none of the providers can be installed

Tags: dockerfile, ubi

I have a dockerfile using registry.redhat.io/ubi8/ubi-minimal as base image. Installed git using microdnf, downloaded few packages, but while trying to remove using microdnf remove git, I get these errors.

`microdnf --enablerepo=ubi-8-baseos  --enablerepo=ubi-8-appstream install git`

```
error: Could not depsolve transaction; 2 problems detected:
 Problem 1: package git-core-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64 requires less, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package git-core-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package git-core-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64 requires openssh-clients, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-core-doc-2.27.0-1.el8.noarch requires git-core = 2.27.0-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package git-core-doc-2.27.0-1.el8.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

Reordering the package dependencies helped to resolve the issue.

`microdnf remove libedit openssh openssh-clients git-core git-core-doc git less` helped.

Wish microdnf also supported dnf's autoremove :(